# Flow is missing props validation when setting default values on an object

Tags: javascript, eslint, flowtype, static-typing

I got a React Functional component which takes a List as props.

```
const Dashboard = (props: { items: List } = { items: List() }) => {
  const { items } = props
  ...
})
```

However, the `items` in `const { items } = props` produces the following error:

`error  'items' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types`

The [FlowType docs](https://flowtype.org/docs/functions.html#es2015-features) give an example:

> ES2015 features Default values assigned to parameters must come after
>   the parameter’s type annotation:
>
> function foo (P1: T1 = V): U { .. }

But it's not really clear to me how this applies to objects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is in fact not a flow error but this eslint error:

https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/prop-types.md

You can resolve your error by disabling the eslint rule if you don't care about proptype now that you use flow.

Or you add a proptype, which is less specific than flow, but runtime.

```
Dashboard.propTypes = {
  items: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot for pointing this out. I'll go with suppression of the error.